# Realoding datatable without dismissing modal pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, datatables

I have a modal popup above a Jquery datatable .I need to add an item to table using the modal text fields.
I use "enter key" key down event to add item to grid; I don't want to dismiss modal after "enter keydown".Every time a item added to datatable by pressing enter on textfield.

Problem here is after I use

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

to refresh grid - the modal pop up dismisses. I need modal closed only after the "OK" is clicked. How to reload background grid without dismissing modal popup?

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data == 'Updated') {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be reloading your page at all. On your success event append the row to datatable dynamically.

If you would like to see how, please put your tables html here so we can help you with that too.

Comment: on Enter press i have to save that item to database which am doing by ajax post;that intern reloads grid with all available rows- am using jquery datables for this purpose.

Comment: Well, I still don't see any reason preventing you from appending rows to table. And if you need to refresh the table, just initialize it as you did on first time.